# How to set ethernet hardware properties as duplex=half?

Tags: networking, xubuntu, ethernet

I have two OS in this PC, and just find that ethernet will only connect to my LAN when with duplex set to half. I discovered this in Windows 7, and want to set up the Xubuntu 16 as well. But I don't know how. I only found a simple setup box with basic configuration as ipv4, MTU, etc..

EDIT: The LAN is a modem-router connected to PCs and a Mac trough ethernet cables 100Mbps. The Macbook uses Full Duplex, but the PC, using the same cable, only connect with Half Duplex.

EDIT 2: The Windows 7 is also configured as 10Mbps and half duplex.

Comment: Something else is wrong with your network. Are you using an ethernet hub or switch? Please describe your network. Cheers, Al

Comment: ethtool should do it. see the man pages, something like `sudo ethtool -s eth0 duplex half`

Comment: "Something like" is kinda vage, must be something right. Can I edit some config file using a text editor? Where is the ethernet config file?

Comment: I wrote "something like" because I don't know your interface name and it was just my quick interpretation of what the man page says. I do not know about any ethernet config file.

Comment: Try another commercial ethernet cable, and try to get full duplex out of your PC, instead of trying to cripple the PC. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please open a terminal and run:

```
ifconfig
```

Verify that your ethernet interface is eth0. If so, then try:

```
sudo ethtool -s eth0 duplex half
```

If you can then connect, let's make the setting permanent:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Add a new line right above 'exit 0':

```
ethtool -s eth0 duplex half
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

If your ethernet interface is enp3s0 or some other, please substitute above.

Comment: When proceeding, I recall about auto negotiation, must be off. Then I start to change the rest. First, I did change the speed from 100 to 10, and it did connect at once. So the problem was really the speed, not the duplex. As in Windows I can change both, I didn't realize was changing both. So my ethernet will "run" at 10Mbps, I will probably need a better card or take a look at BIOS config, but that's another story. But your answer is right, thanks.